# DateTime overlap 3 dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm, date

I am trying to set up an algorithm to detect conflicts between several dates. But I have a problem which is the following:

I have blocks that are programmed on a given date. And I try to detect conflicts. The goal is not to see more than two blocks at the same time

I try to bring up the cases where there are more than two conflicts.
I currently use this method to find a conflict between two dates:

```
Datestart <= @DateEndToTest AND DateEnd >= @DateStartToTest
```

The problem is that I have three conflicts for during one second. Here is a diagram to explain it better:

How to avoid detecting three conflicts at 00:00?

Thanks in advance

The problem is that I always have three conflicts at one time

```
B1 -> start: 2021-12-24 00:00:00 | end: 2021-12-25 00:00:00
B2 -> start: 2021-12-25 00:00:00 | end: 2021-12-26 00:00:00
B3 -> start: 2021-12-24 00:00:00 | end: 2021-12-26 00:00:00
(b3 covers b1 and b2)
```

Three conflicts at 2021-12-25 00:00:00 but I don't want to detect this conflict.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant..)

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images or links.) [mcve]

Comment: For dbms I use mssql

Comment: Images are highly discouraged as a means of providing useful information. A tiny image isn't less help. You may understand your data and your goal completely but no one else does. You need to provide more information which is why a script is requested. And define "detect conflict" as it relates to your sample data - what is your actual goal and what do you desire as "output". And note that you seem to be working with dates only - so don't add confusion by include times with those dates if that is not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

To exclude one, you'll have to change your limit checks.

If you don't want the first one:

```
[DateStart] <= @DateTimeEnd AND [DateEnd] > @DateTimeStart
```

If you don't want the second one:

```
[DateStart] < @DateTimeEnd AND [DateEnd] >= @DateTimeStart
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't solve the problem., I just edited my question

Comment: I assumed you had three conflicts: B3 obviously overlaps with B1 & B2. But B1 overlaps B2 with the <= & >= check.